# emailext jenkinsfile attachment readme

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, email-ext, jenkins-email-ext

Trying to get jenkins to include the readme as an attachment with a pipeline

```
stage('email Alex!'){
      mail(
          body: 'your component is released',
          attachmentsPattern: '**/*.md',
          from: env.DEFAULT_REPLYTO,
          replyTo: env.DEFAULT_REPLYTO,
          subject: 'README',
          to: 'alexander.lovett@bt.com'
      )
  }
```

In this test the dir stucture is:

```
--currentDir
  |--Project
     |--README.md
```

I just get an email with the body and no attachment though :/
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: That should work tried turning on global debug?

Answer (score 2):

You should install this plugin :

`https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin`

And replace your code with this :

```
stage('email Alex!'){
   emailext(
      body: 'your component is released',
      attachmentsPattern: '**/*.md',
      from: env.DEFAULT_REPLYTO,
      replyTo: env.DEFAULT_REPLYTO,
      subject: 'README',
      to: 'alexander.lovett@bt.com'
   )
}
```

Comment: we have emailext installed but for some reason emailext command would not work :/, ended up using mailx command instead.